# Illegal number in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to writing scripts and am trying to start out with a simple one. I am stumped as to why I am receiving the error: `[: 13: Illegal number: count` from the code below. Line 13 is the last `fi`.

```
count=grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" /var/log/****/zlsapp.log | wc -l
if [ count -ge 50 ]
then
    if [ count -lt 100 ]
    then
        exit 1
    fi  
    if [ count -ge 100 ]
    then 
        exit 2
    fi
    exit 0
fi
```

Also is there anyway to do compound if statements like `if(count >= 50 && count < 100)`?

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers - there is no `;` needed to signify `end-of-line` because `then` is on a **new line**.

Comment: `if (( count >= 50 && count < 100 ))` works fine if your shebang is `#!/bin/bash`. Note the double-parens, which create a math context.

Comment: Your original question used `count` with no `$`. My answer addressed that problem. Now you've updated your question, making my answer obsolete. Please don't do that. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141749/167210) on Meta. I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: I've updated my answer; see the explanation at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
count=grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" /var/log/zumigo/zlsapp.log | wc -l
```

probably does not do what you think it does (or you've not accurately copied and pasted your actual code into the question).  If run in the middle of 2014-08-01, it runs the command "2014-08-01 12:00" with the log file as an argument and the environment variable `count` set to the value `grep`, and pipes the output from the probably non-existent command to `wc -l`.

When you subsequently go to test `$count` in the test statements, it is an empty string, which doesn't convert properly to a number.

You probably meant:

```
count=$(grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" /var/log/zumigo/zlsapp.log | wc -l)
```

This captures the output of running `grep` on the log file and piping the output to `wc -l`.

If you run your script with `bash -x` or equivalent (the `-x` option usually shows the execution of the script), you should see this.

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons. **(1)** in bash variables are untyped (could be int, could be char). In order to remove ambiguity, you can specify the type with:

```
declare -i count
```

To tell bash it should be an int. **(2)** you need to dereference your variables with `$` to get the number back. I.E.

```
[ $count -lt 100 ]
```

(it is also good practice to quote your variables - not required, but good practice: `[ "$count" -lt 100 ]`. Drop a comment if you still have trouble.

Comment: If you're going to use bash-only functionality, why not use `(( ))` and get clearer (C-like) math syntax?

Comment: So I tried your suggestions and I still get an Illegal number error but it doesn't give which one it is. Error: `[: 14: Illegal number:`

Comment: Hold on -- I'll copy to my host and check.

Comment: @Michael - Well -- you didn't take the advise of the answer you selected.. Does your code look like this at line **4**: `count=$(grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" log.out | wc -l)` Also, you can assign `count` a value when you `declare` it to insure it is a valid integer. E.g: `declare -i count=0`. That is also good practice :) Your code works fine here after the tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `count` does not refer to the variable `count`; it's simply the string `"count"`.

Change:

```
if [ count -ge 50 ]
```

to

```
if [ $count -ge 50 ]
```

and make the corresponding change elsewhere (but not in the initial assignment).

You should also use double quotes:

```
if [ "$count" -ge 50 ]
```

> Also is there anyway to do compound if statements like if(count >= 50 && count < 100)?

Yes:

```
if [ "$count" -ge 50 -a "$count" -lt 100 ]
```

is likely to work, but the `-a` (logical and) operator is [marked as obsolescent by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). Instead write

```
if [ "$count" -ge 50 ] && [ "$count" -lt 100 ]
```

If you're using bash, `info bash` and search for the "test" command (`[` is an alias for `test`).

And if you're using bash, you should consider using `[[ ... ]]` rather than `[ ... ]` -- or you can use `(( ... ))` for arithmetic expressions. See the [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html) for more information (follow the iink or type `info bash`).

In addition to the missing `$` signs, the first line of your script:

```
count=grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" /var/log/****/zlsapp.log | wc -l
```

doesn't set the `count` variable, since you're not capturing the output of the `grep ... | wc -l` command. To do so:

```
count=$(grep "^$(date -d -30minute +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')" /var/log/****/zlsapp.log | wc -l)
```

(Yes, `$(...)` can be nested.)

Comment: `-a` is marked as obsolete by the POSIX standard; use `[ "$count" -ge 50 ] && [ "$count" -lt 100 ]` instead (two `test` commands in a single `&&` list).